# Has this function a name?

Tags: terminology, trigonometric-series

Has this function a name?

$$f(x) = \prod_{i=2}^{\lceil \frac{x}{2} \rceil} \sin\left( \frac {\pi x}{i}\right)$$

(the product of $\sin( \frac {\pi x}{i})$ for $i=2,3,...,\lceil x/2 \rceil$)

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not certain... looks like just a finite product of sines to me.

Comment: @GustavoMarra: ... yes, but by construction $f(x) = 0$ iff x is an integer and x has a factor less than or equal to $x/2$. It's only a "continuous way" of expressing the factoring problem  :-) From a computational complexity perspective, you can efficiently test if $f(x)=0$ iff you can efficiently find the factorization of $x$. Indeed $i=2,3,..\lceil x^{1/2} \rceil$ is sufficient for the range of $i$

Comment: Oh I see! A clever way of checking factorizations!

Comment: @GustavoMarra: to be more precise if $i=2,3,..\lceil x^{1/2} \rceil$ then $f(x) \neq 0$ iff x is prime (so for the $f$ defined above, we *actually can* check if $f(x)=0$ in polynomial time).  To find the factorization one should be able to check the function for arbitrary ranges of $i$ ... not a great discover :-) ...

Comment: But it can be done with any algebraic software, right?

Comment: It's the Vor function!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't mind calling it Vor's Function :)

Comment: @GEdgar: :-) ... now you could help me to prove that if $f$ is the Vor function, and $g(x) = f(x)*f(x +2)$ then $g(x) \neq 0$ for infinitely many integer positive values of $x$ ... :-D (just kidding)